# unexpected changes in my product page layout?

Tags: product, layout, page

[image]

**unexpected changes in my product page layout that attached in the first screenshot happened to my product page bootstrap layout system .... i can't get back to my default magneto layout as it attached in the second screenshot**

[image]

**and there is the different of the html and css code by the inspect elements in the browser**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit product in admin and check design layout update section and theme setting in magento admin, set layout as no layout update if required and save product.
check screenshot for more details https://www.screencast.com/t/QiD8yKcuzEir

Comment: can you please tell me the steps to access to the page in the screenshot ?